# AngularJS private variable in controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I came across a example online and it got me really confused. Here is the code:

```
angular.module("testApp",[]).controller("testCtrl", function($scope){

    var data = "Hello";

    $scope.getData = function(){
        return data;
    }

    $scope.setData = function(newData){
        data = newData;
    }
});
```

Here is the view:

```
<html ng-app = "testApp">
    <head>
        <script src="lib/Angular.js"></script>
        <script src = "foo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <div ng-click="setData('Hello Hello')">{{getData()}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is how does angular know when to trigger the getData() method in the view. The click event will change the data. However its a private variable, not attaching to the $scope, which means $scope does not watch the change of it, then how does angular know when to call the getData() in the view? I know it maybe a dumb question, but please help! thank you so much!!

Comment: Any chance you have a link to a Fiddle of this working?

Comment: It actually is attached to the $scope as well.

Comment: Ade Attached a Plnkr link below :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The double-curly expression is what AngularJS calls an *observing directive*. During the compilation phase, this directive registers listeners on the expression using the `$watch` method of the scope.

On the other hand, `ng-click` is what AngularJS calls a *listener directive*. This type of directive registers a listener with the DOM instead. Whenever the DOM event fires, the directive executes the associated expression inside an `$apply` call.

This means that after the click expression is executed, a `$digest` cycle will begin. In this cycle, the scope examines all the registered `$watch` expressions (e.g. the double-curly expression containing `getData()`) and calls the listener in case there's a difference from the previous value.

In the end, it is this digest cycle that ensures that all your bound expressions are evaluated.

Comment: This is an even better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The top level controller function runs immediately before it renders the view, in order to initialise the scope. Next the view loads and any logic in the view executes. So when it reaches `getData()` it returns the output of that function at that time.

The clever part is that Angular automatically binds the data in your views all the way back to the data model, so whenever there is a change in the model (i.e. the source of the data) that automatically updates the value in the view and if necessary will run your `getData()` method several times.

I saved it [here as a Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KaTTd0PHK90qkf6OLjWV?p=preview)

Comment: This is a much better explaination :}

Comment: Thank you so much! I like @Razvan Mocanu answer too, but I decide to go for easy explanations :)

Comment: @Razvan's answer is a more technically accurate explanation, although mine is broadly correct in practical terms.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding `{{getData()}}` is a "run on evaluation". So when the DOM renders and angular parses it, it sees the `()` at the end and runs the function. I'll provide citation in a minute when I find it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the getData in angularjs ... or maybe for other uses than the one you are showing right there.

So the right code would be (without getData) :

```
    <html ng-app = "testApp">
    <head>
        <script src="lib/Angular.js"></script>
        <script src = "foo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <div ng-click="setData('Hello Hello')">{{data}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And with getData :

```
    $scope.getData = function(){
        data = 'Hello World';
    }

<html ng-app = "testApp">
    <head>
        <script src="lib/Angular.js"></script>
        <script src = "foo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <div ng-init="getData()" ng-click="setData('Hello Hello')">{{data}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall : What I wanted to say is that the example is working because it's calling setData which is a $scope function. But if you call an internal function which is not linked to $scope and this function changes the data variable, it won't render.